# Calling function within prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting learning OOP in javascript and got stuck with this problem.
I have simple object:

```
function Notifications() {
  this.button = $('#dLabel');
  this.wrapper = $('#notifications');
  this.elements = [];
}

Notifications.prototype = {
  constructor: Notifications,
  fetch: function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: '/notifications.json'
    }).done(function(data) {
      this.elements = data;
      this.refresh();
    });
  },
  refresh: function() {
    console.log("REFRESH");
  }
}


$(function() {
  var ns = new Notifications();

  ns.fetch();
})
```

When I run this I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.refresh is not a function
```

Is it becasue `this` in `.done` function is not `Notifications` instance? How can I fix this ?

Comment: `this` in function in `done()` will be refer to the global object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `bind()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to fix the context:

```
Notifications.prototype = {
  constructor: Notifications,
  fetch: function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: '/notifications.json'
    }).done(function(data) {
      this.elements = data;
      this.refresh();
    }.bind(this)); // <------- Use bind(this)
  },
  refresh: function() {
    console.log("REFRESH");
  }
}
```

The `done()` handler `function(data) {...}` is executed as a simple function invocation, which has the context `this` as the global object (Window) or `undefined` in `"strict mode"`.
The `Function.prototype.bind(newContent)` modifies the context to `newContext`.

[This section](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#23pitfallthisinaninnerfunction) describes in more details how `this` can be lost and how to prevent that.